# Hibernate filter is not working for select and update statement executed inside merge method

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have JPA entities with a filter defined like this:

```
@Filter(name = "tenantFilter", condition = "tenant_id = :tenantId")
public abstract class TenantAwareBaseEntity extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(name = "tenantId", nullable = false)
    private String tenantId;
}
```

I am enabling the filter using the following code before calling the merge method like this:

```
entityManager
             .unwrap(Session.class)
             .enableFilter("tenantFilter")
             .setParameter("tenantId", TenantContext.getCurrentTenantId());
```

When the merge method executes, it executes two sql statements, one select and one update, but when I am checking the sql statements generated for these select and update statements, I am not seeing any filter for tenantId like this:

```
select.....where tenatId = ?

or

update.....where tenantId = ?
```

This filter is working on other methods, but it's not working for merge. Is there any way I can enable the hibernate filter on the merge method?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't make that work for merge. If you code correctly, you shouldn't be able to get access to an entity in the first place when querying with the filter enabled, so there is no reason for Hibernate to consider the filter anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

See this open [PR](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/7722) to change this behaviour as discussed in [HHH-16830](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16830):

> We’ve noted several times that it does actually make sense to apply the filter condition to the where clause of a query resulting from find() (though not to the on conditions which join to-one associations).